# How do i migrate my application from WebSphere to JBOSS EAP 6.2.0.GA?

Tags: migration, websphere, jboss-eap-6

I have my web application currently hosted on WebSphere Application Server 7.0.0.0.
Now i want to migrate my application to JBOSS EAP 6.2.0. GA. 
Has anyone done it before? I need help on below issues.
I want to create following equivalent components in JBOSS.
1) Oracle data source 
--> To create Oracle Data Source, we first definitely need to create Oracle JDBC Provider. So also need to know how to create equivalent to this in JBOSS. 
2) Queue 
3) Activation Specification 
4) Shared library to contain configuration file and third party jars.

How to deploy applications on JBOSS knowldge would be an added advantage.

Yeah, have done some googling and found below links,
http://www.redhat.com/f/pdf/jboss/JBoss_WebSphereMigrationGuide.pdf
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+WebSphere+to+AS+7

But the links doesnt have any practicle knowledge.

Comment: I realize at this point it doesn't do you much good, but there is an up and coming blog post on wildfly.org with a migration from WAS 8.5.5 to WildFly 8.1, https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly.org/pull/39/files. Hopefully it will get published soon.

Comment: James, did that ever get published?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried migrating from websphere to JBOSS\WildFly 10.

Not sure about the other versions of JBoss but wildfly 10 has a configuration xml which you can use to configure your server.

I configured the database, queues, queue factories, namespace bindings using this configuration xml which is available as part of the server installation itself.

The file is present in this location

YOUR_SERVER_INSTALLATION_HOME/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

There are multiple configurations that are possible and you can customize them as per your need as well. You can refer the below documentation for customization.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Subsystem+configuration